# Trouble finding the cartesian equation for a given parametric form

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

I'm given following parametric form

$x = \cos(\sin(s))$ and
$y = \sin(\sin(s))$ for $s \in \mathbb{R}  \setminus 0$

I now need to determine the cartesian equation and draw the curve.
I reasoned that $x^2 + y^2$ would be $\cos^2(\sin(s)) + \sin^2(\sin(s))$ and according to trigonometry that would be $1$.

So that would give me the formula for a circle with a radius $1$. But when I enter it into Wolfram, I'm given another curve: [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20%3D%20cos(sin(s)),%20y%20%3D%20sin(sin(s)))

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See my edit regarding the domain of $s$ - is that what you meant?

Comment: Almost, except 0 isn't a part of it.

Comment: All right, it should be there now.

Comment: I think it may be due to the fact that $-1\le\sin(s)\le1$. Therefore the argments to the $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions for $x$ and $y$ are limited to those (in radians). If instead we just had $x=\cos(s)$ and $y=\sin(s)$ then that would be a circle. But the curve produced by wolfram is still confusing me - I expected it to be just part of a circle - not what looks like paraboloa.

Comment: It does form part of a circle. wolfram probably plots it unconstrained, that's why it looks like a parabola. @Mufasa

Comment: This is what desmos gives: [https://www.desmos.com/calculator/304ihkre4z]